# Reset LayoutParams to what is defined in XML

Tags: android, layout, layoutparams

I can't find a method that does this, but is there a way to reset the LayoutParams on an item?

On rotation of the device, I change the layout params. When I turn back to portrait, I want to change them back to the XML values. Do I just have to define new layout params that match what is in the XML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

before you doing the Rotation , save the initialParams of your item , 
 and after the rotation , when u want to change them back  , u use the layoutParams that u 've saved from beginning

hope that's what you want :)

Comment: just save the LayoutParams of the portrait mode, and after the rotation , you will set the new LayoutParams , and after switching back to portrait mode, just set the LayoutParams saved previously. 
But there is a better and a recommanded solution for this, which is using two different layout files, One for the portrait and the other one for the landscape mode.